# ParserError when trying to read csv file into notebook

Tags: python, csv

I get the following error when trying to read csv file into notebook:
My codes are as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv 
newmessages = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/newmessages.csv')
```

And file is suppose to look like this in an excel file:

[image]

```
pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 5, saw 4
```

Comment: You’re going to have to show us what’s going on in line 5 of the csv file. It’s likely commas present within the string in that line.

Comment: ok I updated the picture

Comment: Line 5 has values in four cells, while the other rows have only one value each. Combine the four cells together into one, and then it should work.

Comment: It looks like quite a few cells have this issue, if it’s only a single column per line you could either go through and use find and replace to eliminate all commas or change the format to use a different delimiter.